# Typo3 7.6.2 LTS with fluid_styled_content and responsive images (picture)

Tags: responsive-images, typo3-7.x, fluid-styled-content

I want to render responsive images with Typo3 7.6.2 LTS and fluid_styled content like this:

```
<picture>
 <source srcset="path_to_small" media="(min-width: 768px) AND (max-width: 991px)">
 <source srcset="path_to_big" media="(min-width: 1200px)">
 <source srcset="path_to_middle" media="(min-width: 992px) AND (max-width: 1199px)">
 <img src="path_to_picture">
</picture>
```

With Typo3 6.2 LTS I've used css_styled_content and I added following Typoscript for this:

```
tt_content.image.20.1.sourceCollection {
 large.mediaQuery = (min-width: 1200px)

 middle.maxW = 1200px
 middle.mediaQuery = (min-width: 992px) AND (max-width: 1199px)

 small.maxW = 992px
 small.mediaQuery = (min-width: 768px) AND (max-width: 991px)
}
```

But this not working with the latest Typo3 version.

I want to edit the fluid_styled_content templates and used the  viewhelper but there are no responsive images yet.

There are another possibility to solve this problem (without extra extension)?

Answer (score 1):

Basically all you have to do, is to create a **lib object** and assign the sourceCollection to it. Then you will be able to call it in your Fluid Template.

**setup.ts**

```
lib.responsiveImage = IMAGE
lib.responsiveImage {
    file {
        import.current = 1
        treatIdAsReference = 1
    }
    sourceCollection < tt_content.image.20.1.sourceCollection
    layout < tt_content.image.20.1.layout
    layoutKey = {$styles.content.imgtext.layoutKey}
}
```

**FluidTemplate.html**

```
<f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.responsiveImage" data="{image.uid}"></f:cObject>
```

This might also help you:

[How to implement the sourceCollection Responsive Image Rendering in typo3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31808505/how-to-implement-the-sourcecollection-responsive-image-rendering-in-typo3)

[How to render responsive images in fluid templates (dce example)
Raw](https://gist.github.com/ArminVieweg/ef22ed696403e583631a)

Comment: That not work for me. Is this for an old version of Typ3?

Answer (score -1):

in fluid_styled_content there is no standalone image-element anymore only the textmedia-element which is "text", "text with image" and "image".

Comment: I know. I want to edit "MediaGallery.html". There are no possibility to create responsive images with <picture> with the latest Typo3 version?

Comment: as far as i know:  not yet.The only way i've found is this extension https://github.com/alexanderschnitzler/fluid-styled-responsive-images.